# Intermittent, temporary freezing

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, ssd

I just got na SSD for my desktop, and decided I'd install Linux on it, for a change from Windows.

The problem is, I've tried Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora 20, and on both, in the install environment and after it's been installed, the whole system freezes for about 500ms-1s roughly every 10 seconds or so.

I've looked in dmesg, kern.log, Xorg.0.log, and /proc/interrupts and nothing is standing out (i.e. no new info in logs after freeze, and no spike in interrupts).

For what it's worth: the 2nd video card (9600), while it and the monitor attached to it are detected, I get no video output on.

Any idea where I can look next to trace down this issue?

Machine:
AMD Phenom Quad-core 2.5Ghz
8gb RAM
nVidia 9600GT
nVidia 210
Creative X-fi soundcard
Asus motherboard (unsure of model at the moment)

Comment: I've seen random hangs like that if you have DNS issues.

Comment: I've seen disk failures causing the problems you are seeing.  In my case, there were no log messages anywhere.  Finally the drive had a HARD failure and replacing it caused these type of problems to go away without anything further changes.

Comment: Looks like it was a problem with the display drivers. Switching to nVidia drivers seems to have temporarily solved the issues.

Comment: I have had the same problem many times. I think it's network related... but the behavior makes Linux on the desktop about as good as Windows :(